# standard/simple way to mount remote directory

Tags: linux, files, mount, shared-folders

There is a shared_data directory in each of my client machines and I want to mount them all in my server. What is the most simple/standard way to do it? NFS seems more suitable for sharing directories in the server to a lot of clients, right? I do have NFS configured for the server. And all OS are debian. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When sharing filesystems, the system that actually has the physical storage for the shared filesystem is normally called the *server*, and any system using the shared storage remotely will be a *client*.

So, in your case, your "client machines" will all need to be NFS or CIFS servers too, and your server system will also be a NFS client.

NFS is equally applicable to both one-to-one and one-to-many sharing. But if your "client machines" cannot be guaranteed to be always running, or if users may shutdown or reboot them at will, you'll probably need an `autofs`-based solution to minimize problems caused by stale NFS mounts and/or unreachable client machines.

This way, you could have the shared_data directories of all the clients accessible as e.g. `/shared_data/<hostname>/` on the server.

First, you would configure all the client machines to share the `/shared_data` directory to the server. I'm assuming NFS here, but `autofs` is equally applicable to CIFS also.

Then, create a NFS automount map file `/etc/auto.shared_data` on the server system, with contents like this:

```
client1 -rw,soft client1.domain.example:/shared_data
client2 -rw,soft client2.domain.example:/shared_data
...
```

Start the NFS client service on the server system, and try mounting the client directories manually to verify that the shared directories are actually mountable.

Then, create a mount point directory `/shared_data` on the server system and reference the map file on the `autofs` master map `/etc/auto.master` like this:

```
/shared_data /etc/auto.shared_data
```

Then start up the `autofs` service on the server system.

Now, anytime you attempt to access any of the `/shared_data/<client hostname>` directories on the server system, `autofs` should automatically mount it for you, and also unmount it after nobody has any files open on it and hasn't accessed it in a while.

The use of the `soft` NFS mount option helps to ensure that an abrupt shutdown of a client system won't leave the processes on the server system with files open on the client's `shared_data` share indefinitely hanging. **Warning:** this opens a possibility of file corruption in some situations. Choose your poison.

If clients are added or removed, you should be able to just edit `/etc/auto.shared_data` and have the changes take effect immediately. Changing `/etc/auto.master` would require reloading the `autofs` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To share a single folder a server to any number of clients machines:

1. NFS:

   - Install NFS service with package manager.
   - Add `/path/to/share IP1(root_squash,rw,async,fsid=1) IP2(root_squash,rw,async,fsid=1) ...`
     to `/etc/exports`, listing the IP range/IPs or the clients.
   - Run `exportfs -ra` to update exports.
   - User permissions will carry over so user 1000 on your client will be treated as user 1000 on your serves.
   - Add `hostname:/path/to/share nfs4 /mount/path timeo=60,intr 0 0` to the each client's `/etc/fstab`
2. CIFS:

   - Install Samba service with package manager.
   - Add folder to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
   - Run `systemctl restart smb` or `smbd` to restart the service.
   - Add authorized user(s) (who must exist on server) with `sudo smbpasswd -a USER`
   - All users can connect with a single username & password if you really want.
   - Add `//hostname/sharename /mount/path/ cifs uid=local_user,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,username=remote_user,password=remote_pass 0 0` to the client's `/etc/fstab`